# Join on compare keys on one side of equals (startswith)

Tags: c#, linq, join

I´m joining two lists, one with bus paths, the other with disk paths that are bus subpaths. So basically I want to join on diskpath.startswith(buspath). The problem is Join On only allows one key on one side of equals.

I want this:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> disksPerBus;

Dictionary<string, string> busesHWPath;  // key Bus Path, Value Bus name
Dictionary<string, string> disksHWPath;  // Key Disk Path, Value Disk name 

from busHWPath in busesHWPath 
join diskHWPath in disksHWPath on diskHWPath.Key.StartsWith(busHWPath.Key)
...
```

The final goal is to get a dictionary (disksPerBus) with the bus name (busHWPath.Value), and all the disks attached to that bus (diskHWPath.Value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values of the bus-dictionary are also unique(your question suggests that):

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> disksPerBus = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
foreach(var bkv in busesHWPath)
{
    string[] disks = disksHWPath.Where(dkv => dkv.Key.StartsWith(bkv.Key))
                     .Select(dkv => dkv.Value).ToArray();
    disksPerBus.Add(bkv.Value, disks); // this may fail if the value is not unique
}
```

Comment: I was going to post my own solution that was the same: busesHWPath.ToList().ForEach(busHWPath => disksPerBus.Add(busHWPath.Value, disksHWPath.Where(diskHWPath => diskHWPath.Key.StartsWith(busHWPath.Key)).Select(diskHWPath => diskHWPath.Value).ToArray()));